# How can you read/decrypt TimeoutData with Raven from NServiceBus?

Tags: ravendb, nservicebus

We are having an issue where we are using sagas that defer messages for timely execution with a versioning variable. The sagas get a date for execution, defer the messages, and send a timeout to cancel the saga set for five days after the last deferred message. This allows people throughout the company to resolve any errors utilizing the saga data within the five days before the timeout.

We also offer an option to requeue deferred messages in the case that business rules change. We have been utilizing this method with much success over the course of the last several months. Recently there was a business rule change, which deferred all messages for a particular client. While all of the saga data seems ok, and it appears that it is resetting the timeouts to expire at the later date. When the deferred messages execute, it is stating the saga no longer exists, when I look at this, I see this as well. Furthermore, I have noticed that the deferred messages do not carry a SagaID. I verified this is nothing new as a bunch of the "still queued" messages do not contain a SagaID neither, but they appear to be executing successfully.

My question regards the ability to read the timeout and deferred message data. I notice they appear encrypted and what I see is an NServiceBus built message. I was curious if there was a way to read the message that is created by NServiceBus.

```
{
  "Destination": {
    "Queue": "clientdata",
    "Machine": "cnapp04"
  },
  "SagaId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "State": "PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pg0KPE1lc3NhZ2VzIHhtbG5zOnhzaT0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMS9YTUxTY2hlbWEtaW5zdGFuY2UiIHhtbG5zOnhzZD0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMS9YTUxTY2hlbWEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vdGVtcHVyaS5uZXQvTHNyLk1pbGl0YXJ5U2VhcmNoLlNlYXJjaC5NZXNzYWdlcyI+CjxRdWV1ZWRTZWFyY2hDb21tYW5kPgo8U2FnYUlEPmIxNmM4NDk5LTc",
  "Time": "2013-09-09T09:00:00.0000000Z",
  "CorrelationId": null,
  "OwningTimeoutManager": "ClientData",
  "Headers": {
    "WinIdName": "COMPANY\\user_name",
    "NServiceBus.Timeout.Expire": "2013-09-09 09:00:00:000000 Z",
    "NServiceBus.OriginatingSagaId": "b16c8499-72f6-4cea-89e1-a18e0101eb82",
    "NServiceBus.OriginatingSagaType": "ClientData.Search.Handlers.SalesPolicy.SaleHandler, ClientData.Search, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
    "NServiceBus.EnclosedMessageTypes": "ClientData.Search.Messages.QueuedSearchCommand, ClientData.Search, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
    "NServiceBus.RelatedTo": "db644e60-5ba1-4d26-a4ef-876855581bd5\\42719333",
    "NServiceBus.TimeSent": "2013-04-01 17:34:42:712194 Z",
    "NServiceBus.Version": "3.2.7",
    "CorrId": null
  }
}
```

Further, how does one utilize the CorrelationID? I am not seeing how this is set.

Answer (score 0):

This state is stored as a byte array.  I'm not a Raven expert so I don't know if you can view this any other way natively.  You may have to have a bit of code to deserialize this object into a readable format.